# Placing a logo in Imageview Layout

Tags: android, imageview

I'm trying to place an information logo in my layout. Because I already got a logo in the top left, I can't manage to get the other logo in the top right, same height. Does someone know the codeline(s) for that?

this is how my layout looks like now, and the red circle explains where I want my logo to be. Can be a few mm away from it, but just not where it is now.

[image: click on this link to see the picture]

This is my layout code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo"
        android:layout_gravity="left" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRightt="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right" 
        android:src="@drawable/informatie_logo" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="  Afspraak   maken" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="  Bezoek  tijden" />

          <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="  Contact" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Route" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Uw mening" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Word vriend" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.03"
            android:text="Folders" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Specialisten" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.97"
            android:text="Brandwond  encentrum" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Nieuws en Agenda" />
     </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Facebook" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Youtube" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Twitter" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="LinkedIn" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can either use a relative layout or club the two imageview inside another horizontal linear layout.

Comment: You can see where the information logo is. I want it to be replaced to where i drew the red circle. So the position has to change a bit.

Comment: @KoenStage Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this part of your code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRightt="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/informatie_logo" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="  Afspraak   maken" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="  Bezoek  tijden" />

          <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="  Contact" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Route" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Uw mening" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Word vriend" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.03"
            android:text="Folders" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Specialisten" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.97"
            android:text="Brandwond  encentrum" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Nieuws en Agenda" />
     </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Facebook" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Youtube" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Twitter" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="LinkedIn" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just to mention add layout_Gravity="right|center_vertical"
inorder to place info image in center

Comment: The place of the logo is correct now, thanks! however, all the buttons are higher than they were, they almost touch the buttons. How can i lower the buttons to where they were without changing the logo's positions?

Comment: @KoenStage try with my answer. and if you want lower buttons with my code then increase value of `margin_top` of `Linear Layout with id LL2`.

Comment: @Koen Stage you can set ''layout_marginTop'' to any buttons you want

Answer (score 0):

Using `RelativeLayout` will help, e.g.:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.MainActivity">


<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/informatie_logo" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="  Afspraak   maken" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="  Bezoek  tijden" />

      <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="  Contact" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Route" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Uw mening" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Word vriend" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.03"
        android:text="Folders" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Specialisten" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.97"
        android:text="Brandwond  encentrum" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Nieuws en Agenda" />
 </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Facebook" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Youtube" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Twitter" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button14"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="LinkedIn" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That places both logo's in the top left, one above the other

Comment: do you have `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` on your second image? I have tested that and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

> Here i have changed your Root Layout to `Relative Layout` because `Linear Layout` will not hold `Margin Top` or `Margin Right` so I have moved out both your `ImageView` outside `Linear Layout` to make it `positioned` as you wanted. And given `Layout_Below` to all child `Linear Layouts`. Apply below **XML** to your Layout.

**NOTE:** Always try to give ID to each Root tag or it's child so it will be easier to identify it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RLMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LL2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="  Afspraak   maken" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="  Bezoek  tijden" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="  Contact" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LL3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LL2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Route" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Uw mening" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Word vriend" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LL4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LL3"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.03"
            android:text="Folders" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Specialisten" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.97"
            android:text="Brandwond  encentrum" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LL5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LL4"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Nieuws en Agenda" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LL6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LL5"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Facebook" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Youtube" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Twitter" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="LinkedIn" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```